# WCF security error when connecting over load balancer to the same server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 3 servers.
Each of them has one WCF service installed.
The client connects to the services through the load balancer.
The load balancer distributes requests to these 3 servers.
When the load balancer redirects the request to the same server on which the client is located, a security error occurs.
When the load balancer redirects the request to another server, everything works fine.

What can be wrong?

Security error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.InitiateUpgradeAsyncResult.OnCompleteAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorAsyncResult.CompleteAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

My WCF Service config:

```
<binding name="bindingName"
         receiveTimeout="02:00:00"
         sendTimeout="02:00:00"
         maxBufferPoolSize="1524288"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="20553600">
  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1024000000" />
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
</binding>

<endpoint
    address="net.tcp://localhost:5555/endpoint"
    binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="bindingName"
    contract="IContract">
    <identity>
        <dns />
    </identity> 
</endpoint>

<behavior name="behaviorName">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="128000"
                     maxConcurrentSessions="128000"
                     maxConcurrentInstances="128000" />
</behavior>
```

Comment: If the service is on the same box as the client, why not use named pipes?

Comment: The client connects to the WCF services through the load balancer which distributes the requests to different servers.

Comment: I get that - but since the client and the service are on the same box, you can save time by simply using named pipes, which is ideal for interprocess communication on the same box.  Rather than going out to the load balancer and then back in to the same or different box.

Comment: I need to distribute the requests between the servers and achieve fault tolerance. One server can not process all requests. And if one of services is down the system should continue to process thе requests.